# Kendo UI Grid not pulling in local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I cannot seem to get the local data (var people) to render in the below kendo grid. Without the people array and the dataSource attribute the columns data renders fine. So not sure where the error is.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="grid">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({

        var people = [{patientName: "John Doe", MRN: "464684778", account: "56765765224768", dateOfBirth: "01/06/2013", room: 403, bed: 22, admitDate: "01/15/2013" }];

                columns: [{title: "Patient Name"},
                    {title: "MRN"},
                    {title: "Account#"},
                    {title: "Date of Birth"}, 
                    {title: "Room"}, 
                    {title: "Bed"}, 
                    {title: "Admit Date"}],

                    dataSource: {
            data:people
        }                   
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things that I see...

1. The people array is inside the grid initialization code
2. You didn't specify fields with your columns.

   ```
   $(function(){

      var people = [{patientName: "John Doe", MRN: "464684778", account: "56765765224768", dateOfBirth: "01/06/2013", room: 403, bed: 22, admitDate: "01/15/2013" }];


      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [{field: "patientName", title: "Patient Name"},
                  {field: "MRN", title: "MRN"},
                  {field: "account", title: "Account#"},
                  {field: "dateOfBirth", title: "Date of Birth"}, 
                  {field: "room", title: "Room"},
                  {field: "bed", title: "Bed"},
                  {field: "admitDate", title: "Admit Date" }],
        dataSource: {
          data:people
        }                   
     });

   });
   ```

Working sample: http://jsbin.com/uxaqus/1

Comment: Thanks so much Burke! Gee, mapping the field data woulda been helpful :-)